# Testcontainers: docker-machine executable was not found on PATH

Tags: docker, testcontainers, testcontainers-junit5

I have two spring boot projects both with the same JDK and running on the same machine (apple m1). The first project is just a dummy project with just testcontainer dependency in it.

While the second project is a legacy project in which i was supposed to integrate testcontainer.

But while testcontainer is running in the first project, for second project I am getting the below error (i have just copy-pasted testcontainer code from the first project)

JDK:azul 15.0.5

JAVA path: Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/azul-15.0.5/Contents/Home/bin/java
Docker Desktop Version: 4.5.0

How to resolve this error?

```
17:15:41.181 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate from class [org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate]
17:15:41.189 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating BootstrapContext using constructor [public org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultBootstrapContext(java.lang.Class,org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate)]
17:15:41.211 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating TestContextBootstrapper for test class [com.housing.cron.ListingUpdateBatchContainerTest] from class [org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper]
17:15:41.218 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Neither @ContextConfiguration nor @ContextHierarchy found for test class [com.housing.cron.ListingUpdateBatchContainerTest], using SpringBootContextLoader
17:15:41.221 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Did not detect default resource location for test class [com.housing.cron.ListingUpdateBatchContainerTest]: class path resource [com/housing/cron/ListingUpdateBatchContainerTest-context.xml] does not exist
17:15:41.222 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Did not detect default resource location for test class [com.housing.cron.ListingUpdateBatchContainerTest]: class path resource [com/housing/cron/ListingUpdateBatchContainerTestContext.groovy] does not exist
17:15:41.222 [main] INFO org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Could not detect default resource locations for test class [com.housing.cron.ListingUpdateBatchContainerTest]: no resource found for suffixes {-context.xml, Context.groovy}.
17:15:41.222 [main] INFO org.springframework.test.context.support.AnnotationConfigContextLoaderUtils - Could not detect default configuration classes for test class [com.housing.cron.ListingUpdateBatchContainerTest]: ListingUpdateBatchContainerTest does not declare any static, non-private, non-final, nested classes annotated with @Configuration.
17:15:41.254 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.ActiveProfilesUtils - Could not find an 'annotation declaring class' for annotation type [org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles] and class [com.housing.cron.ListingUpdateBatchContainerTest]
17:15:41.292 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider - Identified candidate component class: file [/Users/pankajkumar/Desktop/workspace/services/jasprr/cron/target/classes/com/housing/cron/CronApplication.class]
17:15:41.293 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Found @SpringBootConfiguration com.housing.cron.CronApplication for test class com.housing.cron.ListingUpdateBatchContainerTest
17:15:41.360 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - @TestExecutionListeners is not present for class [com.housing.cron.ListingUpdateBatchContainerTest]: using defaults.
17:15:41.360 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Loaded default TestExecutionListener class names from location [META-INF/spring.factories]: [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.event.ApplicationEventsTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.event.EventPublishingTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.restdocs.RestDocsTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.client.MockRestServiceServerResetTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcPrintOnlyOnFailureTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.webservices.client.MockWebServiceServerTestExecutionListener]
17:15:41.372 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Using TestExecutionListeners: [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@3f1c5af9, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener@1c55f277, org.springframework.test.context.event.ApplicationEventsTestExecutionListener@5ddabb18, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener@3e8f7922, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@63192798, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener@50eca7c6, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener@58e6d4b8, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener@1de5f0ef, org.springframework.test.context.event.EventPublishingTestExecutionListener@376a312c, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener@28d6290, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.restdocs.RestDocsTestExecutionListener@6ca0256d, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.client.MockRestServiceServerResetTestExecutionListener@5ef0d29e, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcPrintOnlyOnFailureTestExecutionListener@38f57b3d, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverTestExecutionListener@51850751, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.webservices.client.MockWebServiceServerTestExecutionListener@3ce3db41]
17:15:41.374 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDirtiesContextTestExecutionListener - Before test class: context [DefaultTestContext@1d7f7be7 testClass = ListingUpdateBatchContainerTest, testInstance = [null], testMethod = [null], testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@42f3156d testClass = ListingUpdateBatchContainerTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class com.housing.cron.CronApplication}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true}', contextCustomizers = set[org.springframework.test.context.support.DynamicPropertiesContextCustomizer@46eedc3b, org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@6c2ed0cd, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@51133c06, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@5a3bc7ed, org.springframework.boot.test.web.reactive.server.WebTestClientContextCustomizer@4671115f, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.metrics.MetricsExportContextCustomizerFactory$DisableMetricExportContextCustomizer@46b61c56, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@68df9280, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestArgs@1, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestWebEnvironment@f2f2cc1], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]], attributes = map[[empty]]], class annotated with @DirtiesContext [false] with mode [null].
17:15:41.421 [main] DEBUG org.testcontainers.utility.TestcontainersConfiguration - Testcontainers configuration overrides will be loaded from file:/Users/pankajkumar/.testcontainers.properties
17:15:41.430 [main] INFO org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy - Loaded org.testcontainers.dockerclient.UnixSocketClientProviderStrategy from ~/.testcontainers.properties, will try it first
17:15:41.430 [main] DEBUG org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy - Trying out strategy: UnixSocketClientProviderStrategy
17:15:41.575 [ducttape-0] DEBUG org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy - Pinging docker daemon...
17:15:41.585 [ducttape-0] DEBUG org.testcontainers.shaded.com.github.dockerjava.core.command.AbstrDockerCmd - Cmd: 
17:15:41.595 [ducttape-0] DEBUG com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.InternalHttpClient - ex-00000001: preparing request execution
17:15:41.597 [ducttape-0] DEBUG com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.protocol.RequestAddCookies - Cookie spec selected: strict
17:15:41.598 [ducttape-0] DEBUG com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.protocol.RequestAuthCache - Auth cache not set in the context
17:15:41.598 [ducttape-0] DEBUG com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ProtocolExec - ex-00000001: target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
17:15:41.599 [ducttape-0] DEBUG com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ProtocolExec - ex-00000001: proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
17:15:41.599 [ducttape-0] DEBUG com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ConnectExec - ex-00000001: acquiring connection with route {}->unix://localhost:2375
17:15:41.599 [ducttape-0] DEBUG com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.InternalHttpClient - ex-00000001: acquiring endpoint (3 MINUTES)
17:15:41.599 [ducttape-0] DEBUG com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.io.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - ex-00000001: endpoint lease request (3 MINUTES) [route: {}->unix://localhost:2375][total available: 0; route allocated: 0 of 2147483647; total allocated: 0 of 2147483647]
17:15:41.601 [ducttape-0] DEBUG com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.io.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - ex-00000001: endpoint leased [route: {}->unix://localhost:2375][total available: 0; route allocated: 1 of 2147483647; total allocated: 1 of 2147483647]
17:15:41.605 [ducttape-0] DEBUG com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.io.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - ex-00000001: acquired ep-00000000
17:15:41.605 [ducttape-0] DEBUG com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.InternalHttpClient - ex-00000001: acquired endpoint ep-00000000
17:15:41.605 [ducttape-0] DEBUG com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ConnectExec - ex-00000001: opening connection {}->unix://localhost:2375
17:15:41.605 [ducttape-0] DEBUG com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.InternalHttpClient - ep-00000000: connecting endpoint (3 MINUTES)
17:15:41.606 [ducttape-0] DEBUG com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.io.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - ep-00000000: connecting endpoint to unix://localhost:2375 (3 MINUTES)
17:15:41.615 [main] DEBUG org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy - UnixSocketClientProviderStrategy: failed with exception RuntimeException (java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /private/var/folders/fk/89nf61jd7dvb__ls49mj2q680000gp/T/jna--1700769283/jna11940079618175027996.tmp: dlopen(/private/var/folders/fk/89nf61jd7dvb__ls49mj2q680000gp/T/jna--1700769283/jna11940079618175027996.tmp, 0x0001): tried: '/private/var/folders/fk/89nf61jd7dvb__ls49mj2q680000gp/T/jna--1700769283/jna11940079618175027996.tmp' (fat file, but missing compatible architecture (have 'i386,x86_64', need 'arm64e')), '/usr/lib/jna11940079618175027996.tmp' (no such file)). Root cause UnsatisfiedLinkError (/private/var/folders/fk/89nf61jd7dvb__ls49mj2q680000gp/T/jna--1700769283/jna11940079618175027996.tmp: dlopen(/private/var/folders/fk/89nf61jd7dvb__ls49mj2q680000gp/T/jna--1700769283/jna11940079618175027996.tmp, 0x0001): tried: '/private/var/folders/fk/89nf61jd7dvb__ls49mj2q680000gp/T/jna--1700769283/jna11940079618175027996.tmp' (fat file, but missing compatible architecture (have 'i386,x86_64', need 'arm64e')), '/usr/lib/jna11940079618175027996.tmp' (no such file))
17:15:41.617 [main] INFO org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerMachineClientProviderStrategy - docker-machine executable was not found on PATH ([/Users/pankajkumar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/bin, /Users/pankajkumar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@global/bin, /Users/pankajkumar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/bin, /Users/pankajkumar/.rbenv/shims, /opt/homebrew/bin, /opt/homebrew/sbin, /usr/local/bin, /usr/bin, /bin, /usr/sbin, /sbin, /Users/pankajkumar/.rvm/bin])
17:15:41.617 [main] ERROR org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy - Could not find a valid Docker environment. Please check configuration. Attempted configurations were:
17:15:41.617 [main] ERROR org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy -     UnixSocketClientProviderStrategy: failed with exception RuntimeException (java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /private/var/folders/fk/89nf61jd7dvb__ls49mj2q680000gp/T/jna--1700769283/jna11940079618175027996.tmp: dlopen(/private/var/folders/fk/89nf61jd7dvb__ls49mj2q680000gp/T/jna--1700769283/jna11940079618175027996.tmp, 0x0001): tried: '/private/var/folders/fk/89nf61jd7dvb__ls49mj2q680000gp/T/jna--1700769283/jna11940079618175027996.tmp' (fat file, but missing compatible architecture (have 'i386,x86_64', need 'arm64e')), '/usr/lib/jna11940079618175027996.tmp' (no such file)). Root cause UnsatisfiedLinkError (/private/var/folders/fk/89nf61jd7dvb__ls49mj2q680000gp/T/jna--1700769283/jna11940079618175027996.tmp: dlopen(/private/var/folders/fk/89nf61jd7dvb__ls49mj2q680000gp/T/jna--1700769283/jna11940079618175027996.tmp, 0x0001): tried: '/private/var/folders/fk/89nf61jd7dvb__ls49mj2q680000gp/T/jna--1700769283/jna11940079618175027996.tmp' (fat file, but missing compatible architecture (have 'i386,x86_64', need 'arm64e')), '/usr/lib/jna11940079618175027996.tmp' (no such file))
17:15:41.617 [main] ERROR org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy - As no valid configuration was found, execution cannot continue
17:15:41.618 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDirtiesContextTestExecutionListener - After test class: context [DefaultTestContext@1d7f7be7 testClass = ListingUpdateBatchContainerTest, testInstance = [null], testMethod = [null], testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@42f3156d testClass = ListingUpdateBatchContainerTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class com.housing.cron.CronApplication}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true}', contextCustomizers = set[org.springframework.test.context.support.DynamicPropertiesContextCustomizer@46eedc3b, org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@6c2ed0cd, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@51133c06, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@5a3bc7ed, org.springframework.boot.test.web.reactive.server.WebTestClientContextCustomizer@4671115f, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.metrics.MetricsExportContextCustomizerFactory$DisableMetricExportContextCustomizer@46b61c56, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@68df9280, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestArgs@1, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestWebEnvironment@f2f2cc1], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]], attributes = map[[empty]]], class annotated with @DirtiesContext [false] with mode [null].

Test ignored.

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a valid Docker environment. Please see logs and check configuration
```

First Project pom.xml

4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
2.5.3
 

com.jetbrains
testcontainers-demo
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
testcontainers-demo
Demo project for Spring Boot

<java.version>11</java.version>



org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-web

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.22</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
        <artifactId>testcontainers</artifactId>
        <version>1.16.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <version>1.16.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>1.16.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.aerospike</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-aerospike</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>



</dependencies>



<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 7):

This is a known issue of M1 and Docker [that has been solved](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/issues/3834) with a Testcontainers 1.15.3.

The reason it works for your dummy project and fails for your legacy project is that something in your legacy project overrides the `jna` dependency.

Try to run `mvn dependency:tree` to see which dependency transitively pulls `jna`.

To solve this issue, either `<exclude>` the `jna` from the dependency that pulls it or force the dependency resolution of `jna` >= 5.7.0 with the following:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
       <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
        <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
       <version>5.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused. The OP listed his version of TestContainers as `1.16.3`.  Are you suggesting a downgrade?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue, but it turned out it was because I was using colima. This post here pointed me in the right direction:

https://www.rockyourcode.com/testcontainers-with-colima/

I just needed to set these variables:
export TESTCONTAINERS_DOCKER_SOCKET_OVERRIDE=/var/run/docker.sock
export DOCKER_HOST="unix://${HOME}/.colima/docker.sock"

Answer (score 2):

After upgrading the TestContainers to `1.15.3`, the problem had been resolved, thanks.